# node.js know the file of where the require happened

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, require

I have 2 files

```
// file1.js
//some js code that will do what I ask in the question
module.exports = myFunc

//file2.js
require('./file1')
```

Is it possible, in any kind of way, for file1.js to know who required it? so when file2 requires file1, file1 will know that it was file2?

Comment: Why would you do that? What if two modules both require that one?

Comment: my js-fu is weak, but I'd like for file1 to do create a file with name that includes file2

Comment: If you want this for debugging, look at `new Error().stack`. If you want this for logic, don't, add a layer of abstraction so you can invoke it differently in the first place.

Comment: @PaulS. so it will be better if it will be require('file3')(__filename) and file3 will call the logic in the file1 with the filename recieved?

Comment: We still don't know what you are trying to do. Are you debugging something? Developing a logging library? There are multiple ways to do what you told us but usually it isnt necessary and can be replaced by universal/basic programming patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You noted that you wanted to use `file1`s functionality to create a file that is the same name as the callers. You could do this by utilising the [`__filename`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_filename) variable within a module.

Rather than try and access the caller, just pass this variable when using `file1`. For example:

```
require('./file1')(__filename)
```

Where `file1` has something like:

```
module.exports = filename => {
    // create file here
}
```

While this should solve your problem, it seems like a strange requirement, and there is likely a better way to achieve what you are really after.